# where to manually install django mixin files?

Tags: django, mixins

I'm writing a small desktop app for a client in django and there's a mix in I'd like to use but I don't want them to have to install easy_install and then pip and then the mixin itself every time they install the app. The mixin is "django-file-resubmit", which is seemingly only three files - where should I stash them? or does it depend on the mixin? I am fully aware of the potential maintenance issues, they are not serious in this case.

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `requirements.txt` file is the best way to deal with this, it's pretty much now the universal way of dealing with dependencies. If you're not going to be using pip however, just include it in your project's root under `lib/` and add that directory to your Python path. That's how the old folks done it back in the day. ;-)

Comment: Any idea if adding that dynamically at the start of settings.py with sys.path.append would work?